# How to draw a squircle in R

Tags: r, geometry-surface

This is the code for a rounded square, I wonder if it could get the one for a squircle, which is a very similar figure.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) states that:

> Although constructing a rounded square may be conceptually and physically
>   simpler, the squircle has the simpler equation and can be generalised
>   much more easily.

```
{
  x<-c(1,1,0,0)
  y<-c(1,0,0,1)
  rad <- max(x)/7
  ver<-25

  yMod<-y
  yMod[which(yMod==max(yMod))]<-yMod[which(yMod==max(yMod))]-rad
  yMod[which(yMod==min(yMod))]<-yMod[which(yMod==min(yMod))]+rad

  topline_y<-rep(max(y),2)
  topBotline_x<-c(min(x)+rad, max(x)-rad)
  bottomline_y<-rep(min(y),2)

  pts<- seq(-pi/2, pi*1.5, length.out = ver*4)
  ptsl<-split(pts, sort(rep(1:4, each=length(pts)/4, len=length(pts))) )

  xy_1 <- cbind( (min(x)+rad) + rad * sin(ptsl[[1]]), (max(y)-rad) + rad * cos(ptsl[[1]]))
  xy_2 <- cbind( (max(x)-rad) + rad * sin(ptsl[[2]]), (max(y)-rad) + rad * cos(ptsl[[2]]))
  xy_3 <- cbind( (max(x)-rad) + rad * sin(ptsl[[3]]), (min(y)+rad) + rad * cos(ptsl[[3]]))
  xy_4 <- cbind( (min(x)+rad) + rad * sin(ptsl[[4]]), (min(y)+rad) + rad * cos(ptsl[[4]]))

  newLongx<-c(x[1:2]   ,xy_3[,1],topBotline_x,xy_4[,1], x[3:4],    xy_1[,1],topBotline_x,xy_2[,1])
  newLongy<-c(yMod[1:2],xy_3[,2],bottomline_y,xy_4[,2], yMod[3:4], xy_1[,2],topline_y   ,xy_2[,2])

  par(pty="s")
  plot.new()
  polygon(newLongx,newLongy, col="red")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a base R `squircle` function.
I believe the arguments are self descriptive.

1. `x0`, `y0` - center coordinates.
2. `radius`   - the squircle radius.
3. `n` - number of points to be computed, the default `1000` should make the squircle smooth.
4. `...`      - further arguments to be passed to `lines`. See `help('par')`.

Now for the function and simple tests.

```
squircle <- function(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, radius, n = 1000, ...){
  r <- function(radius, theta){
    radius/(1 - sin(2*theta)^2/2)^(1/4)
  }
  angle <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = n)
  rvec <- r(radius, angle)
  x <- rvec*cos(angle) + x0
  y <- rvec*sin(angle) + y0
  lines(x, y, ...)
}

plot(-5:5, -5:5, type = "n")
squircle(0, 0, 2, col = "red")
squircle(1, 1, 2, col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

## Fernandez-Guasti squircle.

This is another type of squircle. The extra argument is `s`, giving the *squareness* of the squircle.

```
# squircleFG: Manuel Fernandez-Guasti  (1992)
squircleFG <- function(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, radius, s, n = 1000, ...){
  angle <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = n)
  cosa <- cos(angle)
  sina <- sin(angle)
  sin2a <- sin(2*angle)
  k <- sqrt(1 - sqrt(1 - s^2*sin2a^2))
  x <- k*radius*sign(cosa)/(sqrt(2)*s*abs(sina)) + x0
  y <- k*radius*sign(sina)/(sqrt(2)*s*abs(cosa)) + y0
  lines(x[-n], y[-n], ...)
}


plot(-5:5, -5:5, type = "n")
squircleFG(0, 0, 2, s = 0.75, col = "red")
squircleFG(1, 1, 2, s = 0.75, col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: @Ferroao If you modify the exponent it no longer is a *squircle*, but it still is a *superellipse*.

Answer (score 1):

Is the reason to do this yourself, and see if your code can be simplified?

If this is not the case, one possibility is to use the function `grid.roundrect` from the `grid` package.

One example adopted from their help page `?grid::grid.roundrect` is to simply use

```
grid.roundrect(width=.5, height=.5, name="rr", gp = gpar(fill = "red"))
```

Comment: good, didn't knew. I found not so good to have to write the r (The radius of the rounded corners) in units